# Process XML node as Independent XML Document and update the node in Original XML document

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom

I need process a XML node as independent XML, add a new tag to the Node Document  , update the original XML document with the new node info. Any help, advice or tutorial is welcome.

This is the original XML:

```
    <ENVOLVENTE id="ENVOLVENTE">
<FirmaEmpresa>
    <FirmaDonante>
        <Firma>
            <Relacion>
                <RelacionId>32490342093249090234</RelacionId>
            </Relacion>
            <Formulario>
                <Donante>
                    <DonanteNombre>Gloria Robles</DonanteNombre>
                    <DonanteCorreo>gloria@gmail.com</DonanteCorreo>
                </Donante>
                <Beneficiado>
                    <BeneficiarioPais>USA</BeneficiarioPais>
                    <BeneficiadoCorreo>usdonations@gmail.com</BeneficiadoCorreo>
                </Beneficiado>
                <Fabricantes>
                    <Fabricante>
                        <FabricanteNumeroOrden>1</FabricanteNumeroOrden>
                        <FabricantePais>MX</FabricantePais>
                        <FabricanteCorreo>fabricante@gmail.com</FabricanteCorreo>
                    </Fabricante>
                </Fabricantes>
                <ListaDonaciones>
                    <Donaciones>
                        <DonacionesNumeroOrden>1</DonacionesNumeroOrden>
                        <DonacionesProductoId>nombre</DonacionesProductoId>
                        <DonacionesCantidadDonada>100</DonacionesCantidadDonada>
                        <DonacionesFechaDonacion>2016-12-29T12:21:16</DonacionesFechaDonacion>
                    </Donaciones>
                </ListaDonaciones>
            </Formulario>
        </Firma>
    </FirmaDonante>
    <Empresa>
        <EmpresaPais>MX</EmpresaPais>
        <EmpresaNombre>Donaciones A.C </EmpresaNombre>
        <EmpresaDirecccion>AV. REFORMA 1900</EmpresaDirecccion>
        <EmpresaCiudad>CDXM</EmpresaCiudad>
    </Empresa>
    <PermisoEmpresa>
        <PermisoNumero>329023409324902349023409234</PermisoNumero>
    </PermisoEmpresa>
</FirmaEmpresa>
</ENVOLVENTE>
```

Now, i need extract the node  "FirmaDonante" to a new  XML DOM:

```
 <FirmaDonante>
        <Firma>
            <Relacion>
                <RelacionId>32490342093249090234</RelacionId>
            </Relacion>
            <Formulario>
                <Donante>
                    <DonanteNombre>Gloria Robles</DonanteNombre>
                    <DonanteCorreo>gloria@gmail.com</DonanteCorreo>
                </Donante>
                <Beneficiado>
                    <BeneficiarioPais>USA</BeneficiarioPais>
                    <BeneficiadoCorreo>usdonations@gmail.com</BeneficiadoCorreo>
                </Beneficiado>
                <Fabricantes>
                    <Fabricante>
                        <FabricanteNumeroOrden>1</FabricanteNumeroOrden>
                        <FabricantePais>MX</FabricantePais>
                        <FabricanteCorreo>fabricante@gmail.com</FabricanteCorreo>
                    </Fabricante>
                </Fabricantes>
                <ListaDonaciones>
                    <Donaciones>
                        <DonacionesNumeroOrden>1</DonacionesNumeroOrden>
                        <DonacionesProductoId>nombre</DonacionesProductoId>
                        <DonacionesCantidadDonada>100</DonacionesCantidadDonada>
                        <DonacionesFechaDonacion>2016-12-29T12:21:16</DonacionesFechaDonacion>
                    </Donaciones>
                </ListaDonaciones>
            </Formulario>
        </Firma>
    </FirmaDonante>
```

After that, I will modify the node as new XML document, something like that, with a new XML Element after the original Node.

```
        <FirmaDonante>
        <Firma>
            <Relacion>
                <RelacionId>32490342093249090234</RelacionId>
            </Relacion>
            <Formulario>
                <Donante>
                    <DonanteNombre>Gloria Robles</DonanteNombre>
                    <DonanteCorreo>gloria@gmail.com</DonanteCorreo>
                </Donante>
                <Beneficiado>
                    <BeneficiarioPais>USA</BeneficiarioPais>
                    <BeneficiadoCorreo>usdonations@gmail.com</BeneficiadoCorreo>
                </Beneficiado>
                <Fabricantes>
                    <Fabricante>
                        <FabricanteNumeroOrden>1</FabricanteNumeroOrden>
                        <FabricantePais>MX</FabricantePais>
                        <FabricanteCorreo>fabricante@gmail.com</FabricanteCorreo>
                    </Fabricante>
                </Fabricantes>
                <ListaDonaciones>
                    <Donaciones>
                        <DonacionesNumeroOrden>1</DonacionesNumeroOrden>
                        <DonacionesProductoId>nombre</DonacionesProductoId>
                        <DonacionesCantidadDonada>100</DonacionesCantidadDonada>
                        <DonacionesFechaDonacion>2016-12-29T12:21:16</DonacionesFechaDonacion>
                    </Donaciones>
                </ListaDonaciones>
            </Formulario>
        </Firma>
    </FirmaDonante>
    <Signature>
            <SignedInfo/>
            <KeyInfo/>
    </Signature>
```

Finally, i need add the Node document in the same position in the original document, as Node, with the new tag:

```
    <ENVOLVENTE id="ENVOLVENTE">
<FirmaEmpresa>
    <FirmaDonante>
        <Firma>
            <Relacion>
                <RelacionId>32490342093249090234</RelacionId>
            </Relacion>
            <Formulario>
                <Donante>
                    <DonanteNombre>Gloria Robles</DonanteNombre>
                    <DonanteCorreo>gloria@gmail.com</DonanteCorreo>
                </Donante>
                <Beneficiado>
                    <BeneficiarioPais>USA</BeneficiarioPais>
                    <BeneficiadoCorreo>usdonations@gmail.com</BeneficiadoCorreo>
                </Beneficiado>
                <Fabricantes>
                    <Fabricante>
                        <FabricanteNumeroOrden>1</FabricanteNumeroOrden>
                        <FabricantePais>MX</FabricantePais>
                        <FabricanteCorreo>fabricante@gmail.com</FabricanteCorreo>
                    </Fabricante>
                </Fabricantes>
                <ListaDonaciones>
                    <Donaciones>
                        <DonacionesNumeroOrden>1</DonacionesNumeroOrden>
                        <DonacionesProductoId>nombre</DonacionesProductoId>
                        <DonacionesCantidadDonada>100</DonacionesCantidadDonada>
                        <DonacionesFechaDonacion>2016-12-29T12:21:16</DonacionesFechaDonacion>
                    </Donaciones>
                </ListaDonaciones>
            </Formulario>
        </Firma>
    </FirmaDonante>
    <!--NEW TAG -->
    <Signature>
            <SignedInfo/>
            <KeyInfo/>
    </Signature>
    <!--NEW TAG -->
    <Empresa>
        <EmpresaPais>MX</EmpresaPais>
        <EmpresaNombre>Donaciones A.C </EmpresaNombre>
        <EmpresaDirecccion>AV. REFORMA 1900</EmpresaDirecccion>
        <EmpresaCiudad>CDXM</EmpresaCiudad>
    </Empresa>
    <PermisoEmpresa>
        <PermisoNumero>329023409324902349023409234</PermisoNumero>
    </PermisoEmpresa>
</FirmaEmpresa>
</ENVOLVENTE>
```

actually,  i can  extract the  Node, but i have errors when i try  to add a new Element  the node document:

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                xmlFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Document document = builder.parse(stream);


         Element elementFirmaDonante =  (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("FirmaDonante").item(0);



        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();       
        Document documentoCODExporterMasEH = documentBuilder.newDocument();


        Node newNode = documentoCODExporterMasEH.importNode(elementFirmaDonante, true);
        documentoCODExporterMasEH.appendChild(newNode);



        /*In this point all is OK, a can serialize de Document, but now, a can't add a new Item to the node document*/


        /*
         * This block, throws error:
         * HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.
         */
        Element anotherElement =  (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("Empresa").item(0);
        Node anotherNewNode = documentoCODExporterMasEH.importNode(anotherElement, true);
        documentoCODExporterMasEH.insertBefore(anotherNewNode, newNode);
```

The above code is just to test  that I can add new Elements or nodes to the DOM Object.

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code, I am able to insert a new node before Empresa node:-

```
Element anotherElement  = (Element)document.getElementsByTagName("Empresa").item(0);
    Element newTag = document.createElement("Signature");
    Element childElem1=document.createElement("SignedInfo");
    Element childElem2=document.createElement("KeyInfo");
    newTag.appendChild(childElem1);newTag.appendChild(childElem2);
    anotherElement.getParentNode().insertBefore(newTag, anotherElement);
```

Try to change your code like below:-

```
documentoCODExporterMasEH.insertBefore(newNode,anotherNewNode);
```